# Гостеприимство и гостеприимность

Tags: значения, словоупотребление

I recently came across the two words гостеприимство and гостеприимность. Can someone explain how гостеприимность is different from гостеприимство? Examples where гостеприимность would be used but гостеприимность can not would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel there is no difference except that "гостеприимность" is a really rare word, probably a new variation of "гостеприимство" that uses the other way of forming the abstract noun (гостеприимный → гостеприимность).

I decided to use brute force and look in "Russian National Corpus"... 7 instances of "гостеприимность" for almost 230 million words of corpus.

But it does not sound wrong. At least, to my ear.

Answer (score 9):

гостеприимность is a characteristics of somebody or something.
(english -ness suffix).
гостеприимство is a substantive form derived from the word гостеприимный.
(english -ship suffix)

Answer (score 1):

Those can be used synonymously

> Мы показали гостям **свое гостеприимство / свою гостеприимность** и доброжелательность.

However, `гостеприимство` is far more widespread in spoken and [written form](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE,%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=25&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE;,c0;.t1;,%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C;,c0), whereas an increase of using `гостеприимность` [can be observed](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=25&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C;,c0) only since the second half of the last centuryю

Answer (score -3):

Гостеприимство is a readiness and willingness of a person to greet and feed the guests. 
Гостеприимство is a quality of a person or a nation.

Comment: please be noted that you actually twice mentioned the same word in your explanation, thus it does not answer the question.